# Why Interface in Case 1 throws compile time error but in Case 2 compiles successfully

Tags: java, interface, overloading

I am having two interfaces in "CASE 1" in which I have same method with different return types and I am extending both the interfaces in another interface then I am getting compile time error as return types are incompatible for inherited methods but here when we are extending two interfaces in third interface then methods are getting overloaded and in method overloading return type of method has no effect then why is this giving error.

Also if I am same methods in two interfaces with same return types in "CASE 2" and extending both the interfaces in third interface then here I am not getting any errors. Why?

## CASE 1

## Interface1.java

```
public interface I1
{
int m();
}
```

## Interface2.java

```
public interface I2
{
void m();
}
```

## Interface3.java

```
public interface I3 extends I1,I2
{

}
```

## CASE 2

## Interface1.java

```
public interface I1
{
int m();
}
```

## Interface2.java

```
public interface I2
{
int m();
}
```

## Interface3.java

```
public interface I3 extends I1,I2
{

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first case, the interface is inconsistent. It would be *impossible* for any class to implement it, as it can't satisfy the constraints of "there must be an `int m()` method" and "there must be a `void m()` method".

You say "in method overloading return type of method has no effect" - that's not quite true. In method overloading, the return type isn't part of the signature. You can't overload methods by changing just the return type, precisely *because* they have the same signature:

```
class Foo
{
    public void m() {}
    public int m() { return 1; }
}
```

Result:

```
error: method m() is already defined in class Foo
```

In your second case, the interface is consistent. It's entirely possible to implement it, just with a single method `int m() { ... }`. The fact that the single method would be used to implement both `I1.m` and `I2.m` is not a problem.